# How to disable URL sharing

Tags: high-sierra, dock, sharing, web-browser, bonjour

On macOS High Sierra (perhaps also earlier version of macOS), I noticed that when I open a URL in a webbrowser (tested with Safari and Opera), that on other Macs in the local network, the Docks shows an additional icon of the local browser on the left hand side. When I click this icon, it opens the URL that is open on the other Mac.

[image: Dock with additional browser icon]

I have three questions: How does this (technically) work, how is this feature called, and how do I disable it?

As for the technology, I assumed that the URL of the frontmost browser window would be shared using a discovery service (DNS-SD, formerly Bonjour), but I couldn't detect it with a Bonjour browser. My second thought is that it is some kind of AirDrop technology, but I couldn't find it there either. So I'm not sure if this is sharing on a local LAN, or sharing using the same iCloud account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called [Handoff](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl732d3c0a/mac) & is part of [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl1d734309/10.14/mac/10.14), enabling seamless working between all your devices.

As far as its underlying structure, Continuity uses Bluetooth, WiFi & internet connectivity, all linked via your iCloud account.
Handoff itself requires Bluetooth, so works at short distance only.

> **Turn Handoff on or off**
>
> Note: If you don’t see a Handoff option on your device, it doesn’t
>   work with Handoff.
>
> - On your Mac: Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, click General, then select “Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices”
>     (below “Recent items”). To turn it off, deselect the option.
> - On iPad, iPhone or iPod touch: Go to Settings > General > Handoff, then tap to turn on Handoff. To turn it off, tap the option.
> - On Apple Watch: Open the Watch app on iPhone, go to My Watch > General, then tap to turn on Enable Handoff. To turn it off, tap the
>     option.